# Running a specific code continuously while the program is running/A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

```
Thread changeSize = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChangeSize));
public void ChangeSize()
{
    this.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
}
```

I have the following code snippet. My goal is to run "this.Size = new Size(Scre..." continuously while the program is running. My idea is to create a thread that does this for me, but I get the "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" error. I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me how should I fix this problem, or how should I run "this.Size = new Size(Scre..." continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all and most importantly, if your goal is listening/synchronizing to current screen size, this seems like a really inefficient way to do it.

You would have to run a loop in your ChangeSize method to poll over and over again - and suspend execution after each iteration for some time as surely you don't want to keep a CPU core busy just needlessly polling as fast as it can.

Long story short though, I heavily recommend looking into some system event that tells you when the screen size changes; just a quick google, but https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged(v=vs.110).aspx seems like it will get you there.

---

As for your initial question - very much pointing out again that I would not use this!! You would either have to make ChangeSize static, or use something such as

```
Thread changeSize = new Thread(delegate () { ChangeSize(); });
```

Keep in mind you would, in either case, two threads reading/writing to the same memory, so you would also have to keep thread-safety in mind.